# Multiple objects into Hierarchy tree C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface, hierarchy

Within my MVC project, I have a hierarchy tree helper class that that renders objects in an hierarchal tree view. I have managed so far to render a list of 'Event' object types, including an indefinite amount of sub-events.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezVst.jpg)

Additionally, the Event (or sub-event) object can contain one or more Alerts. I want my hierarchic tree to render all Alerts for all Events as well. My HierarchyTree helper class only accepts one type of Object however. This is the code configuring my node, currently accepting an **Event** object

```
u.Events = GetBLLFactory().EventLogic().GetEventsByTemplateID(id.Value).ExtractFromResult();

var eventconfig = new HierarchyTreeItemPropertyConfig<Event>()
            {
                GetIDFunc = e => e.EventID,
                GetNameFunc = e => e.Name,
                GetParentIDFunc = e => e.ParentEventID,
                GetSortOrderFunc = e => e.SortOrder.Value,
                SetNameFunc = (e, name) => e.Name = name,
                SetParentIDFunc = (e, parentID) => e.ParentEventID = parentID,
                SetSortOrderFunc = (e, order) => e.SortOrder = order,
            };

u.EventHierarchyTree = u.Events.ToHierarchyTree(eventconfig);
```

And this is the code within my Model, also built around the Event object:

```
public class TemplateItemModel
{
    public HierarchyTree<Event> EventHierarchyTree { get; set; }
}
```

Furthermore, these are my object properties:

**Alert**

```
public class Alert : BaseEntity
{
    public int? AlertID { get; set; }
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

**Event**

```
public class Event : BaseEntity
{
    public int? EventID { get; set; }
    public int TemplateID { get; set; }
    public int? UserRoleID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentEventID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public int? Duration { get; set; }
    public int? SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

My question being, how would I go about feeding my HierarchyTree helper object with one object being either an Event or an Alert. I want my HierarchyTree to render both object types in their correct hierarchal order:

Event > SubEvent > Alert

Event > Alert

I'm fairly sure interfaces are what I need, however I have little experience regarding interfaces and I can't figure out how to feed an interface to this Hierarchy helper :-(

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: wouldnt your `Event` object just need a `public List<Alert> Alerts {get;set;}` property?

Comment: i suppose the correct way might be to use `public virtual ICollection<Alert> Alerts {get;set;}`

Comment: Alerts are separate objects from Events in the sense that an Alert can (later on) be assigned to a certain User and receive a status (like 'read' or 'unread') which differs from the Event status property.

Comment: regardless, you have `public int EventID` on class `Alert` so the foreign key is there.. might as well include it on the `Event` class as well